# Powershell; pipe stdout to commandline

Tags: command-line-interface, powershell, redirection

As an example, I would like the following commands to put a dir listing with all subdirectories to StdOut

```
@'
>> -R
>> '@ > .\test
>>
dir `test`
```

So, after the first four lines, there's a file in the current directory called `test` containing `-R` (recurse). Line four doesn't work, of course, but I would like the result to be the same as

```
dir -R
```

. Perhaps a better for line 3 is

```
echo `test`
```

where I hope the result is

```
/s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
"Get-Childitem $(Get-Content test)" | Invoke-Expression
```

or

```
"dir $(type test)" | iex
```

`Invoke-Expression` is roughly equivalent to Bash's `eval`. It's a good idea to be cautious of any security implications of its use.

Comment: Echo Dennis' comment regarding security.  Could the input to Invoke-Expression be manipulated to gain an advantage?

Comment: @Simon: Yes, the contents of the file (named "test" in this example) could include `;del *` which would be executed by `Invoke-Expression` causing files to be deleted, for example.

Comment: @Joey: But in the case of the OP's question, that would treat the file contents as the name of a file to do the `gci` on instead of as an option to `gci`.

Comment: Ah, sorry; skimmed the question a bit too shallowly. Agreed, then it's a quite dangerous thing to do. You could perhaps read the file, tokenize the contents and build a hashmap from it. After that you can use the splat operator (provided you're on PS2) to explicitly only use them as arguments to `gci`, negating the option to inject other commands (at least as far as I can see now).